# Using Hard drives from Old MacPro1.1 Dual Core Intel

Tags: mac, macbook-pro, mac-pro

I have an old MacPro1.1 Dual Core. I'm looking for advice on whether or not the hard drives from this machine will be accessible using new my MBP M2, what sort of adapter I'd need and anything else I might not be aware of being trying.

Comment: Typically I would put the drive in a compatible USB carrier, attach it, and see if I could read the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drives will be completely compatible, current macOS can still read & write HFS drives.

You just need to find a suitable SATA -> USB caddy. It must be externally powered to handle 3.5" disks. USB alone is not sufficient; it needs the 12V rail - so that's the only criterion you need to add to your search.
Specific product recommendation is off topic.